# Openlayers dynamic filtering/styling of geojson layer

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I'm working with Openlayers and overlaying a geojson file representing species type over OSM. I have an HTML form that allows users to select a species type and I then need to filter the geojson layer based on the selection. I then want the map to redraw, displaying only the filtered features.

I've tried CQL and messed around with styling but I'm not getting very far. Does anyone have any experience of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

James

Answer (score 5):

The `OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON` read operation takes in a filter function see [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON.OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON)

## OR

You could do something like this:

```js
if (html.checked == true) {
    feature.style.display = "block";
} else {
    feature.style.display = "none";
}
```

Working [Example/DEMO](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/geojson.html)

[image]

Comment: I was with you on the Cat and Alligator, but you lost me with the elephant drawing...I'm just not seeing it.  :-D

Comment: @Vadim : LOL. It's only the profile of its head (ear and trunk)  and the trunk is pointed at the cat. It's a work of art. And yes these animals are to scale. ;)

Comment: thanks for your help @CaptDragon, really appreciate it. I'll give it a try. I presume you aren't from West Africa? High crocodile mortality rates....

Comment: Yes, high mortality rates from the same Croc.

Comment: I've got that working, cheers, well sort of. Initially the subset of features is drawn on submitting the form value but a split second later the layer redraws to include all features. Almost there I think but when init() is called on reload it redraws the whole layer.

Comment: @CaptDragon the link is dead; Is it possible to have a working link?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I'm sorry that hosting expired and all the files I had on there are gone :/. I tried looking for it on my HD and other hosting but no luck.

Comment: Well, looks like we lost it to the crocodiles.

Comment: looks more like a rhino than an elephant to me